# Unknown Column In Where Clause mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

My query is `$query = "SELECT * FROM cartmatch WHERE CARTNO=$cart4";` and I'm receiving an error that says "Unknown column 'M833' in 'where clause'". Just so you know, cart4=M833.

::EDIT::
For some reason, nothing is showing. Here is the code on the page.

```
<?php
$cart1 = rawurldecode($_GET["path"]);
list( , , , , , $cart2) = explode ("\\", $cart1);
$cart3 = $cart2;
list($cart4) = explode (" ", $cart3);

$con = mysql_connect("SERVER","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("cartmatch", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cartmatch WHERE CARTNO='$cart4'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="album.php" method="POST">Please enter press save.<br><br><input name="ID" type="hidden" value=';
echo $_GET["ID"];
echo ' ><input name="enabled" type="hidden" value=';
echo $_GET["enabled"];
echo ' ><input name="artist" type="hidden" value=';
echo $_GET["artist"];
echo ' ><input name="title" type="hidden" value="';
echo $_GET["title"];
echo '" >Name:<br/><input name="album" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="';
echo $row['ALBUM'];
echo '" ><input type="submit" name="edit" value="Save"></form>';
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM cartmatch WHERE CARTNO='$cart4'";` try it.

Comment: For some reason it's not showing anything. I edited my question.

Comment: Why? Give some more informations.

Comment: @Piotr: +1 enclosing the string literal in single quotes (just as you suggested) should fix the "unknown column" exception.

Comment: It did, but the page shows up blank when loaded.

Comment: can you do a `var_dump($cart4);` and paste the output here?

Comment: @Nerd-Herd where would I put that?

Comment: Just after this statement: `list($cart4) = explode (" ", $cart3);`

Comment: I think that's the problem. It should only be M833

Comment: @Nerd-Herd `list($cart4) = explode (" ", $cart3);` should have been `list($cart4) = explode ("+", $cart3);`. If you would like to answer the question with that, I can take you as the correct answer if you want. Or I can answer it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the query to:

```
"SELECT * FROM cartmatch WHERE CARTNO='$cart4'"
```

and change

```
list($cart4) = explode (" ", $cart3);
```

to

```
list($cart4) = explode ("+", $cart3);
```

Comment: for some reason I'm still having troubles...it might be somewhere else in my code

Answer (score 1):

Change the WHERE section to

```
CARTNO='$cart4'
```